# Aligning 2 different sets of fading images

Tags: html, css

please excuse my absolute naivety and lack of understanding, I'm really not even a beginner.

I'm trying to align 2 different sets of images that fade to show a different image underneath. I have been able to understand enough code to get the fades to work but for some reason the pictures are on top of each other not next to each other.

I'm sure this is an easy fix but I've searched the net and nothing I've tried has worked.

Here is my current code.

```
<body style="background-color:black;">

<style>

#cf {
  position:left;
  height:850px;
  width:550px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

#cf img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}


#cf1 {
  position:relative;
  height:850px;
  width:550px;
  margin:0 auto;
}

#cf1 img {
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 2s ease-in-out;
}

#cf1 img.top:hover {
  opacity:0;
}

.none {cursor: none;}

</style>

<body>

<div id="cf1"><div id="cf"> 
<p class="none">
  <img class="bottom" src="2.png" />  
  <img class="top"  src="1.png" /> 
</p>
</div>


<p class="none">
  <img class="bottom" src="4.png" />
  <img class="top" src="3.png" />
</p>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

The images show, the images fade, the mouse disappears all of that works, but no matter how I fiddle with the positioning it never solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, change #cf's position from "left" to "relative".

Second, you can't give all the images (in your case -2) the same position and expect that they won't cover each other.

If you want absolute position you can use pseudo selector for the images in order to... Positon them.

Generic Example:

```
#cf img {position:absolute;to:0;left:0;width:100px;height:100px}
#cf img:last-child {left:110px}
```

Comment: I might have wrote it in a confusing manner. The 2 sets of pictures, only cover themselves. by on top of each other I mean they are layered like bullet points, 1 set, then below them the other set. but i'd like it to be one set followed by the other both on the same horizontal.